# Upload file location for 2 different web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a site written in C# (ASP.NET Core v2.1) with 2 Web Application projects inside the Solution, one for Admin and one for the site. The Admin project has image upload function and the image then will be used in the main site.

Now I'm confused how do I take the uploaded images from the Admin site and show it in my main site? I know I can do it if I just save the image binary in my DB, but what if I want to save it as a file? Am I just better off with saving it as binary in my DB or is there any other option?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Save the file in admin solution, and access it with  adminurl/<imagepath> or expose controller to load file from admin